# Exit loop with pynput input

Tags: python, pynput

The purpose of my code is to continuously type a letter very fast. It starts when a certain key is pressed (in this case f3) and stops when another key is pressed (f4). My code looks like this currently.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Controller, Listener
import time

keyboard = Controller()
confirm = False


def on_press(key):
    if "f3" in str(key):
        global confirm
        confirm = True
        while confirm:
            keyboard.press('e')
            keyboard.release('e')
            time.sleep(0.10)
    elif "Key." in str(key):
        pass


def exit_loop(key):
    if "f4" in str(key):
        global confirm
        confirm = False
    elif "Key." in str(key):
        pass


with Listener(on_press=on_press) as ListenerStart:
    ListenerStart.join()

with Listener(on_press=exit_loop) as ListenerEnd:
    ListenerEnd.join()
```

My problem is that, while starting the program with the f3 key works, I am unable to stop the program with f4. Also, the program is supposed to be paused, not exited from. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you run `while`-loop which blocks all code - you should run it in separated thread.

Comment: you sould use one Listener with `on_press` which check what key was pressed and set some variable like `started = True`, `paused = False`, etc, And it should use these variables to run or skip code inside `while`-loop which should run in separated thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have long-running code like `while`-loop then you have to run it in separated thread - because it blocks current code and it can't check if you press `f4`.

If you want to pause code then you should use some variable - ie. `paused = True` - to control if code inside `while`-loop should be executed or skiped.

And then you need only one `Listener` to check keys and check if `paused` is `True` or `False`

```
from pynput.keyboard import Controller, Listener
import time
import threading

def function():
    keyboard = Controller()
    
    while True:
        if not paused:
            keyboard.press('e')
            keyboard.release('e')
        time.sleep(0.1)

def on_press(key):
    global paused
    
    if paused:
        if "f3" in str(key):
            paused = False
    else:
        if "f4" in str(key):
            paused = True

# global variables with default values at star
paused  = True

# run long-running `function` in separated thread
thread = threading.Thread(target=function)  # function's name without `()`
thread.start()

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

---

In corrent code you could use the same `f3` to start and pause loop.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Controller, Listener
import time
import threading

def function():
    keyboard = Controller()
    
    while True:
        if not paused:
            keyboard.press('e')
            keyboard.release('e')
        time.sleep(0.1)

def on_press(key):
    global paused
    
    if "f3" in str(key):
        paused = not paused

# global variables with default values at star
paused = True

# run long-running `function` in separated thread
thread = threading.Thread(target=function)
thread.start()

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

---

This code could be more complex - `f3` could check if `thread` already exists and create thread when it doesn't exist.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Controller, Listener
import time
import threading

def function():
    keyboard = Controller()
    
    while True:
        if not paused:
            keyboard.press('e')
            keyboard.release('e')
        time.sleep(0.1)

def on_press(key):
    global paused
    global thread
    
    if "f3" in str(key):
        paused = not paused
        if thread is None:
            # run long-running `function` in separated thread
            thread = threading.Thread(target=function)
            thread.start()
            
# global variables with default values at star
paused = True
thread = None

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```