# Is it possible to create a custom Keyboard Interrupt key in Python?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, keyboard, keyboardinterrupt

I am writing a python script that has an infinite loop and for me to stop I use the usual Keyboard Interrupt key ***Ctrl+c*** but I was wondering if I can set one of my own like by pressing ***space*** once the program can stop I want it to have the same function as ***Ctrl+c***
So if it is possible how can I assign it?

Comment: Well, this is more a question of setting up your terminal/IDE/whatever. Some might have the functionality to rebind keys.

Comment: See here is my problem I want to be set within the script so whoever has access to the code will press the same universal button to sop the code

Comment: There are many ways you could go about this:  
1. Set up your terminal/IDE (I might be able to help)   2. Create a global keybind (I can recommend a library and how to use it)    3. Look at STDIN in a thread (No clue how you would do this)

Comment: By that you mean create like a hotkey for the task

Comment: Which one are you talking about?

Comment: By creating a global key bind

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240502/discussion-between-ktibow-and-sam-acc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from pynput.keyboard import Listener
     while True:
         if keyboard.is_pressed("space"):
             exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a listener to check when your keys are pressed and then stop your script

```
from pynput.keyboard import Listener

def on_press(key):
    # check that it is the key you want and exit your script for example

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()

# do your stuff here
while True:
    pass
```

Comment: So in the def function I put the key I want to assign?

Comment: It's not working can you apply it to this code so I can see how this works https://www.online-python.com/L9lTSey4GH

Comment: def on_press(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        raise KeyboardInterrupt

Comment: You cannot make it work on an online executor since keys are manage by the navigator

Comment: yeah  just write the code even if it doesn't work because I can't seem to understand how I am supposed to arrange the code

Answer (score 0):

For creating the keyboard listener ([Based on Jimmy Fraiture's answer and comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70509690/5424535)), and on <kbd>Space</kbd> stop the script using `exit()` ([Suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19782075/how-to-stop-terminate-a-python-script-from-running))

```py
from pynput.keyboard import Listener

def on_press(key):
    # If Space was pressed (not pressed and released), stop the execution altogether 
    if (key == Key.space):
        print('Stopping...')
        exit()

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()


while True:
    print('Just doing my own thing...\n')
```

Comment: thank you I will try this now and keep you posteed

Comment: that did not work

Comment: As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67875573/exit-loop-with-pynput-input), you will have to create another thread to be responsible for the listener. But that makes me think you will have to use some of the other "stop"-commands I linked in my answer, because now you not only want to kill the listener, but _also_ the thread doing your while-loop.